# Execute a section of code depending on a probability

Tags: c

If I have a probability between 0 and 1 where 1 executes every time and 0 never executes, how would I implement that into my code?

For instance, I have a probability of 0.8, how would I program a section of code to run 80% of the time.

I assume we used the rand() function but I don’t know how to implement that.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Have you read the documentation on the `rand` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would be an example of how to implement what you're trying to do:

```c
int main() {
    double probability = 0.8;
    srand(time(0));
    double randomNumber = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
    if (randomNumber < probability) {
        // execute code
    }
    return 0;
}
```